# How to remove the spring animation in a Flutter PageView when flinging

Tags: flutter

I'm using a [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) to scroll through multiple months in a schedule app.

Here's the (simplified and pretty standard) build method:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Roster"),
        body: PageView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return RosterMonth(
            month: _monthList[index].monthOfYear,
            year: _monthList[index].year,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now the `ScrollPhysics` of the `PageView` make the pages "bounce" when flinging left-right ([video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1md8a5jGhMcjdOQM9cyIMeiVZCjdlDD0S)) and I'd like to get rid of this effect.

I've tried to create a custom version of `PageScrollPhysics`, but only with limited success. Overriding `minFlingVelocity` to return a high value (`double.maxFinite` for instance) will indeed remove the effect, but making the feeling of a fling very unnatural (since it stops being an actual fling I guess). What would be the correct way to remove the spring effect (and get the same effect like with a ViewPager in Android)?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the official way to remove the bounce effect is to use **ClampingScrollPhysics** as the physics parameter. I don't really know if that solves your issue with the fling feeling being unnatural. But for me this was exactly what I wanted.

```
PageView(
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      controller: _controller,
      children: [
        Container(color: Colors.red),
        Container(color: Colors.blue),
        Container(color: Colors.green),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: That does work for the edge pages, but not for the ones in between unfortunately ...